# post to facebook wall using selenium and python

Tags: python, facebook, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am using firefox 18.0 and selenium webdriver with python(2.7) bindings on windows 7. Using all this I have been able to log in to facebook, go to an user's page , send text to the wall post field. but when i make it click post, it doesn't post. I have observed that when I send the keys to the wall post field, the text appears faded, but when i manually type into the field, the text appears dark. This might be the problem. I started doing this to see if it could be done...for no real purpose.. but now that it doesn't work, its driving me crazy. Any ideas?

```
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
    driver.find_element_by_id("email").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys("mailid@email.com")
    driver.find_element_by_id("pass").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id("pass").send_keys("password")
    driver.find_element_by_id("u_0_4").click()

    #i wanted to post multiple times.. but it doesn't work even once
    for i in range(1,11):
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/<username>")
        el=driver.find_element_by_id("u_0_1r")#post field
        el.clear()
        print i
        el.click()
        el.clear()
        el.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(1)
        el.click()
        #assume fwords is a list of words
        el.send_keys('test output: '+random.choice(fwords))
        el.click()
        el.click()
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.find_element_by_id("u_0_1m").click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@id='u_0_1l']/div/div[4]/div/ul/li[2]/label/input").click()
        time.sleep(8)
```

Comment: el is the post field . i click on it before writing to it. doesn't work. _I have observed that when I send the keys to the wall post field, the text appears faded, but when i manually type into the field, the text appears dark._ this still happens even if i click on the field.

Comment: Did you read about the graph api: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/?

Comment: @Gregor Yes, I did. but i want the posts to be from my id and not some app. And im quite certain im missing something here.. if it works for everything else but the final post.. its got to be some issue with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works well with the chrome driver for selenium.

Comment: am getting confused in finding the right id or elements to make a post. It full of div only .Cant find this either  el=driver.find_element_by_id("u_0_1r")#post field  . In my case am logged in just not able to make a post . I am directly accessing the post input section from the main page without visiting the userpage