# How to identify Facebook timeline element to post something with Robot Framework?

Tags: selenium, testing, robotframework

Can you help me **to identify element** ID or any other locator of timeline composer **in Facebook** profile ?

I need this to use in Robot framework with selenium2library to post something on my wall.

I can log in to Facebook, navigate to profile, but I cant input text into timeline composer. I tried to use Click element before inserting text, but no success.

I am using "inspect element" in browsers/firebug add-on to identify elements.
In this case, unfortunately all locators I have tried giving errors like:

> Element does not appear in 5 seconds

or

> Element must be user editable in order to clear it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275313/post-to-facebook-wall-using-selenium-and-python

Comment: Yes thx, but this Q is also unsolved :(

Comment: uh, the linked post seems to be solved when using ChromeDriver. You can't just use ChromeDriver to satisfy that?

Comment: You might also want to post in the Selenium forums as this is a question on that. You can then adapt any answers you get to RF. Similarly you can also post your questions to RF forums (on Google Group, LinkedIn group).

Answer (score 0):

Non dynamic locator for FB timeline-composer has name "xhpc_message_text" (18.10.2016)

```
Input text      name=xhpc_message_text  test
```